# Replacement of value in byte array producing odd outcome

Tags: java, android, arrays, byte

So I am sending some stuff over bluetooth, for this I am using byte arrays, one of the byte arrays I am using I need to change one of the values before I send it, using this...

```
private void sendIntensity(int I){
    intensity[3] = (byte) i;
    sendIntensity();
}
```

The original byte array is made up like this:

```
private byte[] intensity = new byte[]{58,0,42,0,10,13}
```

I am getting the intensity from an edit text, getting the text and using regex to find the intensity they want to use, I use

```
int option = Integer.parseInt(text);
```

To do that. Basically, any number under 128 works perfectly, I can see this because I log the values in the array, setting it to 127 will log `58, 0, 42, 127, 10, 13` but when I do 128 or over I get a weird set of data when I log it.

The max number I will be putting in there is 255.

When I log what is in the array when use `intensity[3] = (byte) 128;` I get back `50, 0, 42, -17, -66, -128, 10, 13`

When I log what happens when I use 129 I get back `50, 0, 42, -17, -66, -127, 10, 13`

What is happening? Why am I not just getting back `50, 0, 42, 128, 10, 13` like I should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `byte` range is `[-128, 127]`, if you try to set a value larger than `127` in a `byte`, it will do a round trip to `-128`, `-127` and so on.

From the SCJP 6 book:

```
byte a = (byte) 128;
```

> (...) what's the result? When you narrow a primitive, Java simply truncates
>   the higher-order bits that won't fit. In other words, it loses all the bits to the left of
>   the bits you're narrowing to.

More info:

- [Java Primitive Data Types](http://www.javacamp.org/javaI/primitiveTypes.html)
- [Java in a Nutshell: Primitive Data Types](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch02_04.htm), check the **Type Conversions** section, the *narrowing conversion* part.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply due to byte characteristic in java upto 128 from -128 thats all

Comment: It's just up to Java? Really? How about [C and C++ behavior on narrowing](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~spl/Academic/ProgrammingLanguages/commentary/NarrowingAndWideningConversions.html)?

Comment: Sorry , your question is tagged with java so I answered this.I am not sure about C or C++.

Comment: what I tried to say is that narrowing concept is present not only in Java but almost all LPs.

Comment: ok then what do ask me ? you are asking me the difference between java and C or C++ in this case?